# runtime optimization of multithreading code

Tags: c#, multithreading, optimization

Sorry for my last question, my code was so stupid.
My base situation is: I want to construct a state tree which has 8! items in the last state. so the total count of iterations is about 100.000 (8!*2 + 7! + 6! + ... )

it currently takes less than one second, i need to construct it every time my artificial intelligence is making a move. Of course, the alpha/beta search is a solution but before thinking of that i want to optimize my code so i really have the best possible performance.

what i already did: 
tried to replace every LINQ function with precalculations or collections with faster access (Dictionary), more precalculations for skipping whole operations, of course, some approximations to spare heavy calculations, using List constructors only when there's actually a change, if not, just use the reference.
there'll be more calculations coming so i really need more ideas for reducing. maybe something about what collection is fastest for my purpose.

[My code](https://github.com/Kokujou/Hanafuda/blob/master/Assets/External/Scripts/KI/Searching/SearchingStateTree.cs)

It's about the BuildChildNodes function and the called TryCollect function. My Constructor is doing some little precalculations. my state tree knows everything, even the cards which aren't actually shown.

as the comment came up: i'm not asking you to read and understand my code to provide content-wise advices. i'm asking you about the functions, operators, data types and classes i'm using and if there could be make a replacement which runs a bit faster. e.g. if there's a faster collection for my purpose or if you have a better idea to replace the collections constructor with a faster method reagarding of adding and removing afterwards.

**Edit**: okay List is definitely the best type i can use. i tried [] Arrays and even Dictionaries () and last of all i even tried LinkedLists. All with a significant loss.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [tour] and [ask]. You're basically asking _"Optimize these 150 lines of code for me, see it on GitHub"_. That's not really how this site works. Also, your title is in German.

Comment: waaah! i'm so sorry i really totally mixed my languages up!

Comment: okay fixed. second: i know i can't ask people to optimize 150 lines of code. i'm asking for advices that can help reducing my runtime while providing my code as an example of what i already did. so you see what classes and operations i'm using. it's not about understanding the code on it's whole, i just hoped somebody could overlook it and spot out some time intense functions.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that `RemoveAt()` could be expensive at it is proportional to the size of the list.

You can always use the Visual Studio performance profiler to find out where you should optimize your code the most.

If you can find a way to use fixed-size arrays that you allocate when your program starts, instead of dynamically-allocated data structures like `List`, you will save of lot on memory allocation management overhead.

Comment: sadly i can't. I'm using unity, this combination doesn't support that :( sadly... plus it's multithreading code, thats even more complicated.

i thought removing via index is the fastest way... how do i do something like Add efficiently on an Array? don't i have to iterate through it, too? otherwise i don't know the last item which isn't null

Comment: I do not know the specifics of your algorithm, but there are other data structures like linked lists (which can be maintained with fixed-size arrays) where you can add / remove elements in constant time.

Comment: then i might try them out. i can limit the array sizes. that'd be really nice. maybe i can replace the removal process with just creating a new list and adding just the neccessary items instead of adding all and then removing. that could be good! thanks!

Comment: Yes, that would be faster!

Comment: if you see any other things i can improve, tell me :3 i just noticed that i'm copying my collections 3 times, that's unneccessary too.

Comment: You should try the Visual Studio performance profiler. It will tell you all about the number of calls made not just to your functions but also calls to the .NET library functions, and the time spent in each call. It is really nice.

Comment: okay... i just replaced my Lists through Arrays but... somehow the speed decreased... thats weird. it wasn't even much to do... it seems Lists provide something that makes accessing the array faster.

Comment: When I said arrays, I was not talking about the Array class, but plain old array variables, like a[].

Comment: i know. thats what i was talking about too... i just even hyped it and used dictionary, even worse. it might be because i'm not really looking things up. i'm numerating through them (btw for enumerating, whats better for or foreach?), but maybe adding is more important for my algorithm...

Comment: you know: the card on the hand are just gradually removed, the collections are gradually added, the field gets both and the deck is just passed as a reference. maybe i need a different type... i'll try linked lists now

Comment: Re: for or foreach, it depends on the data structure that you iterate through. If you iterate over a List<>, foreach is faster than for which will retrieve every element with its index. When you optimize, you first optimize the time complexity of an algorithm (this is where you can make the most gain), and then you can optimize its implementation in code.

Comment: so you say it may be because i blindly replaced my types or did i misgot that? well you sure got a point... i now used a dictionary just for my deck since this one's just passed by reference and is looked into... it's basically readonly.... maybe i should even do it readonly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193920/discussion-between-kyoshiro-kokujou-obscuritas-and-mathusalem).